# Easy way to detect if sprite was touched?

Tags: java, libgdx, touch, sprite

I have two sprites and they need to be touched at the same time so I made two Vector2 xy and xy1.

```
//xy = x and y coordinate of pointer 1
//xy1 = x x and y coordinate of pointer 2

//faces is the class for the sprites

 if(xy.x >= faces.faceSpr.getX() && xy.x <= faces.faceSpr.getX() + faces.faceSpr.getWidth() &&               //detecting if xy and xy1 are inside the sprites
                    xy.y >= faces.faceSpr.getY() && xy.y <= faces.faceSpr.getY() + faces.faceSpr.getHeight() &&         //*
                    xy1.x >= faces.faceSpr1.getX() && xy1.x <= faces.faceSpr1.getX() + faces.faceSpr1.getWidth() &&     //*
                    xy1.y >= faces.faceSpr1.getY() && xy1.y <= faces.faceSpr1.getY() + faces.faceSpr1.getHeight())      //*
                score += 1;
            else if(xy1.x >= faces.faceSpr.getX() && xy1.x <= faces.faceSpr.getX() + faces.faceSpr.getWidth() &&        //*
                    xy1.y >= faces.faceSpr.getY() && xy1.y <= faces.faceSpr.getY() + faces.faceSpr.getHeight() &&       //*
                    xy.x >= faces.faceSpr1.getX() && xy.x <= faces.faceSpr1.getX() + faces.faceSpr1.getWidth() &&       //*
                    xy.y >= faces.faceSpr1.getY() && xy.y <= faces.faceSpr1.getY() + faces.faceSpr1.getHeight())
```

I haven't tested yet if this code works, is there an easier and better way of doing it?

EDIT:

I tried to use getBoundingRectangle() method and it works but I have problem on setting it's postion.

```
sprite.getBoundingRectangle().setPosition(x,y);
// then I check if it works
System.out.println(sprite.getBoundingRectangle().getPostion);
```

but the result is always 0.0, 0.0

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Get the rectangle of it and make a contains call.

```
sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(new Vector2D(touch.x,touch.y)); //or
sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(touch.x, touch.y); //
```

Make sure that you unprojected correct.

Comment: with contain it will give true only when one sprite is completly in other sprite I think correct method will be overlaps or intersects, but not conatains for sure, op needs to know when touched not when fully inside